# WooCommerce - Loop de produtos, filtrando pelo atributo da variação

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estou criando um filtro para listar os produtos que tenham a opção diurno ou noturno, selecionados dentro de uma variação. Consegui um loop que chega bem perto, mas está trazendo todos os produtos que tem a variação turmas, independente do valor do select. A idéia é trazer somente os produtos que tenham a opção diurno selecionada dentro da variação turmas. Alguém pode me dar um help por favor?

Segue o código:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_turmas',
            'field' => 'periodo',
            'terms' => 'noturno'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

php exibe produtos de categoria woocommercer.
opa blz amigo passei por uma dificuldade semelhante apos muita pesquisa achei esse 
fontes
[Listar somente os produtos da categoria wp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/340691/listar-somente-os-produtos-da-categoria-wp)

Meu Codigo fico assim

```
       $args =

       array (
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'per_page' => '12',
        'columns' => '4',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'product_cat' =>'secadores',
      //  'tag_ID' => '116'
    );

 /*    array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
        );    

        */

     $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

   /*     $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); */
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
          //  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>

            <li style="width: 33.0%!important;" class="product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-mesa-de-sinuca-e-jantar product_cat-mesa-de-sinuca-personalizada first instock sold-individually shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">    

            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>
                <?php 
                    if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) 
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog');                                               
                    else echo '<img class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="255px" />'; 
                ?>
            </a>    
            <div class="collection_desc clearfix">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" class="collection_title">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>                                        
            </div>
            <div class='row'> 
                <div class=''>                                  
                    <div class=' custom-title-product'>
                        <a href=".$link.">
                            <h3 class='custom-title-product'><?php echo $title ?></h3>
                        </a>                        
                    </div>
            <div class='text-center custom-value'>
                <span>                              
                    <?php echo $currency . $valor ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class='text-center'> 
                <span class='custom-inf-parcela '> ou em até <?php echo $qt_parcela ?> x de </span> 
                <span class='custom-valor-parcela'>  R$ <?php echo $parcela ?> </span> 
                <span class='custom-inf-parcela '> na entrega </span>
            </div>
            <div class='text-center'>
                <span class='custom-inf-parcela '> ou apenas </span>
                <span class='custom-valor-parcela'> R$ <?php echo $avista ?> </span>
                <span class='custom-inf-parcela '> à vista na entrega <span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>                           
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->      
  <?php          
         //   wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
         //    endwhile;
        } else {
           echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        //  wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
            </ul><!--/.products-->
```